# How to allow a different user to execute graphical applications

Tags: macos, google-apps

I am trying to find a way to su to a user and run a graphical applications (My goal is to run another instance of google drive but for now - just running any application would be fine). I am basically looking for an equivalent of xhost + from Linux.

Currently when I try running iTerm for example as a different user I get:

```
FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer
```

So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: What's the full command you're running that leads to that error message?

Comment: Thanks, for example:
sudo su - differentuser -c "/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm"
Password: ...
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.

Comment: See the duplicate question for the syntax. You want to use target `/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm` for the `sudo` call to start iTerm as another user.